# Error: Carthage not found. Install using `brew install carthage`

Tags: java, appium-ios, carthage

I am trying to do a UIAutomation using Appium and using Eclipse IDE and whenever I try to run the code through a testng.xml file, it fails to install WebDriverAgent on Phone/Simulator. If I run the same code without using XML file it works fine without issue. Here are the logs:

```
Error: Carthage not found. Install using `brew install carthage.`
    at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (../../lib/logging.js:63:13)
    at checkForDependencies$ (../../../lib/wda/utils.js:59:9)
    at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartFailed' logged at 1508135361248 (11:59:21 GMT+0530 (IST))
[debug] [XCUITest] Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "Carthage not found. Install using `brew install carthage`".
[debug] [XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying
[XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes
[debug] [XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaStartAttempted' logged at 1508135372395 (11:59:32 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Launching WebDriverAgent on the device
```

Comment: I'll just ask the obvious, do you have carthage installed through brew install?

Comment: Yes. It is installed. Facing this issue only if I try to run the code using testng suite(testng.xml)

Comment: Did you use `brew` under the same user or being `sudo`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed issue by doing the following steps:

```
1) Right click on your project > Run as > Run Configurations
2) Select Environment tab
3) Click on select option and select PATH environment
4) Edit Path variable using Edit option
5) Update path value with carthage location /usr/local/bin and select append env to native env
6) Apply changes and run the test.
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Environment path as "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

[SET PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7B7Ar.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Appium` is running from the current user that you're logged in with:

In Terminal:

```
lsof -n -i:4723 | grep LISTEN
```

The output should be something like:

```
node    488 your-user-here   21u  IPv4 0xf2aca68f2aca68ff      0t0  TCP *:4723 (LISTEN)
```

**What I've done wrong:** I added a startup config to `/Library/LaunchAgents` to start Appium automatically with system startup but this produced the errors: "Carthage not found" because the owner of the process was `root`, not my specific user who installed `carthage` with brew.

So be careful setting up the startup scripts for Appium. Running with `root` user it won't find the PATH that you have with your specific user.